# Create a decorator to handle token validation in flask

Tags: python, flask

I have two endpoints defined in my flask service python file.

1. The first endpoint returns a list of parent and child nodes from a mmap json file which it parses.
2. The second endpoint returns a specific child field from a mmap json file which it parses.

Each of these endpoints can only be used when the token has been validated. Thus I have the following implementations.

```
from flask import request
import requests

def check_token(self):
   # Method to verify the token from the another python Service
   token_header = request.headers['authorization']
   # Remove the 'Basic" part from the token
   auth_token = token_header.split(maxsplit=1)[1]
   self.__payload = {'token' : auth_token} 
   # Append the token to the header by using the payload
   response = requests.get(self.__url, params=self.__payload, verify=False)
   return response

# 1. This endpoint returns a list of parent and child nodes from a mmap json file which it parses.
class SystemList(Resource):

   def get(self, systemname):
      token = check_token()
      if token.ok:
         # Open the mmap file, parse it, and jsonify the result and return it
      # Invalid token present
      else:
           return make_response(
                jsonify("Invalid access as token invalid.")
            )

# 2. The endpoint returns a specific child field from a mmap json file which it parses.
class SystemChildList(Resource):

   def get(self, systemname, id):
      token = check_token()
      if token.ok:
         # Open the mmap file, parse it, and jsonify the result and return it
      # Invalid token present
      else:
           return make_response(
                jsonify("Invalid access as token invalid.")
            )
```

The issue I have is that I want to use a decorator to handle the validation of the token.

I want to be able to add it before the `get()` method something like the following.

```
@validatetoken
    def get(self, designation):
       # I am not sure what goes here and what do I need to put here?
       # I want to be able to have one decorator for both of the SystemList and SystemChildList 
       # resource shown above.
```

I am not sure on what goes in the decorator. I am really new to these concepts. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [method_decorators](https://flask-restful.readthedocs.io/en/0.3.5/extending.html#resource-method-decorators) parameter to achieve this

try,

```
from flask import request
from functools import wraps
import requests

def check_token(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def decorated(*args, **kwargs):
        token_header = request.headers['authorization']
        # Remove the 'Basic" part from the token
        auth_token = token_header.split(maxsplit=1)[1]
        __url = "url_for_token_validation"
        __payload = {'token' : auth_token} 
        # Append the token to the header by using the payload
        response = requests.get(__url, params=__payload, verify=False)
        if response.status_code != requests.codes.ok:
            return make_response(
                jsonify("Invalid access as token invalid.")
            )
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
    return decorated


# 1. This endpoint returns a list of parent and child nodes from a mmap json file which it parses.
class SystemList(Resource):
    @check_token
    def get(self, systemname):
        # Open the mmap file, parse it, and jsonify the result and return it

# 2. The endpoint returns a specific child field from a mmap json file which it parses.
class SystemChildList(Resource):
    @check_token
    def get(self, systemname, id):
        # Open the mmap file, parse it, and jsonify the result and return it
```

Comment: is this decorator only applicable to the get() methods or will it be for all the methods in the Resource. I am a bit confused about that.

Comment: It is applicable for all the methods(if there are more) for that class

Comment: If I only want it to be applicable to the get() method, then how would I do that?

Comment: In that case apply `check_token` as a method decorator for get methods only
ex: https://www.learnpython.org/en/Decorators

Comment: May you please update your code to reflect this? I realise that it is just adding a ```@check_token``` right?

Comment: I have another question. If the token is not valid, would I still be executing the lines of code in the get() function?

Comment: Nope. return make_response... would send out error response back to the client

Comment: So if I handling the valid case in the comments in the ```def get(self, systemname):
        # Open the mmap file, parse it, and jsonify the result and return it```, then it would not get executed. What do you mean by the "client" here? May you please elaborate

Comment: Client is whoever calling this API

Comment: Your actual code written in get method will get executed if the token is valid. That is when return f(*args, **kwargs) is called

Comment: Thank you so much. Much appreciated

Comment: One last question, is the part ```if not response.ok:``` execute when the response.ok is not 200? I tried to even just put ```if response.ok:``` to see if it executes the return statement, but it doesnt, am I missing sth here?

Comment: As per the doc(https://pypi.org/project/requests/0.5.1/), "Response.ok
(Bool) will beTrue if no errors occurred during the request, and the status_code is kosher."
I guess you should use `response.status_code == requests.codes.ok` for a more reliable check @Anna

Comment: So I believe that would mean to replace ```if not response.ok:``` with the code ```if response.status_code != requests.codes.ok:```? Please do let me know and would you also please update ur answer so it could help someone else in the future